# Too few arguments to function route(),

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use the index method of a resource controller but I get this error.

```
Too few arguments to function route(), 0 passed in D:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaHNF\storage\framework\views\c3a3dac715e2000606fb9805bd8426410ba15b72.php on line 14 and at least 1 expected (View: D:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaHNF\resources\views\gestionEspecialidades.blade.php)
```

I'm going to post the code in the view that tries to access the method and the code of the index method in the controller.

**View Code (this is in app.blade)**

```
<li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{ route('especialidades.index') }}">{{ __('Gestion especialidades') }}</a>
                    </li>
```

**Controller code**

```
public function index(){
   $especialidades = Especialidades::all();
   return view ('gestionEspecialidades',compact('especialidades'));
}
```

I dunno why I get the error if the index method doesn't require any parameters, the route is a resource route

**Route Code**

```
Route::resource('/especialidades', EspecialidadesController::class);
```

I'm new in Laravel so I don't have any idea what is giving me this error.
What I'm trying to do with that navbar is when I click in Gestionar Especialidad to run the index method to show all the values in a table in the view gestionEspecialidades, going to post the code of the view that I want to use the index method.

**Second View code**

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h1>Gestión Especialidades</h1>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr class="info">
            <th>Nombre</th>
        </tr>
        @foreach ($especialidades as $especialidad)
            <tr>
                <td>{{$especialidad->nombre}}</td>
                  
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </table>

    
</div>
@endsection
```

What can be the cause of the error? Help will be appreciated. (English is not my main language so sorry for any mistakes, if you need more details or more code I can gladly update the question.)

**Framework/view code**

```
<?php $__env->startSection('content'); ?>

<h1>Gestión Especialidades</h1>
<div class="container">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <tr class="info">
            <th>Nombre</th>
        </tr>
        <?php $__currentLoopData = $especialidades; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $especialidad): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo e($especialidad->nombre); ?></td>
                <td><a href="<?php echo e(route()); ?>"></a> Editar </td>
                 <td><a href="<?php echo e(route(/*Ruta para formulario Eliminar */)); ?>"></a> Eliminar</td>   
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; $__env->popLoop(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
    </table>

    <a class= "btn btn-primary" href="formularioEspecialidad">Registrar especialidad</a>
</div>
<?php $__env->stopSection(); ?>

<?php echo $__env->make('layouts.app', \Illuminate\Support\Arr::except(get_defined_vars(), ['__data', '__path']))->render(); ?><?php /**PATH D:\xampp\htdocs\SistemaHNF\resources\views/gestionEspecialidades.blade.php ENDPATH**/ ?>
```

Comment: did you define this resource route under a route group? you can check the route list as `php artisan route:list`

Comment: How define the resource group under a route group? I did the command and was able to see the index, it shows like this "GET|HEAD  | especialidades | especialidades.index   | App\Http\Controllers\EspecialidadesController@index"    @Espresso Dunno if that means something is wrong.

Comment: What's version of laravel you using?

Comment: 8, now I can see what can maybe be my mistake, I have the functions as protected, Can that be the cause? I think they should be Public.

Comment: Yup, You should public function index

Comment: Already did that @Ryan but I still get the same error

Comment: Can you paste code of file `views\c3a3dac715e2000606fb9805bd8426410ba15b72.php`?

Comment: @Ryan Updated the question with the code you asked for

Comment: Forget it, problem solved. I had some incomplete routes that tried to place later and those looked like the cause of the issue. Thanks for the help @Ryan, sorry for any trouble caused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with route:

```
Route::resource('especialidades', 'EspecialidadesController');
```

Comment: Thanks but already solved, I had some incomplete routes in the for each in the view and that was causing the problem.